# How can I make this Java delay webservice call code use less cpu?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have been doing some cpu profiling of my application, and I note that one of the things that takes a significant amount of time is the code that ensures I send mo more than query to webservice per second. The actual query itself and handling of the results take little time in comparison, of course there is an I/O component waiting for results but they thing I am trying to do is reduce cpu since the applications sometimes has to run on a single cpu machine

Using **YourKit Profiler** the call that uses the significant amount of cpu is

```
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.aquireQueued()
```

My delay method is below

```
    public class SearchServer
    {

        private static java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock delayLock = new ReentrantLock();
        private static AtomicInteger queryQueue = new AtomicInteger();
        private static AtomicLong queryDelay = new AtomicLong();

        static void doDelayQuery()
        {
            delayLock.lock();
            try
            {
                if(isUserCancelled())
                {
                    return;
                }
                //Ensure only send one query a second
                Date currentDate = new Date();
                long delay = currentDate.getTime() - querySentDate.getTime();
                if (delay < delayInMilliseconds)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        long delayBy = delayInMilliseconds - delay;
                        queryDelay.addAndGet(delayBy);
                        Thread.sleep(delayBy);
                        logger.info(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":Delaying for " + delayBy + " ms");
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ie)
                    {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        throw new UserCancelException("User Cancelled whilst thread was delay sleeping");
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //We set before unlocking so that if another thread enters this method before we start query we ensure they
                //do not skip delay just because the query that this thread has delayed for has started
                querySentDate = new Date();
                delayLock.unlock();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ever heard of a ScheduledExecutor? Sleeping is obviously the wrong approach here.

Comment: @Rhangaun yes I am aware of that, but that seems to be just for when you are submitting to something to happen at a particular time, or if you want same task to occur at regular intervals. In my case different tasks are submitting tasks to this and alwasy want it to occur as soon as possible but I need to throttle it to prevent overloading the server. Jut had an idea maybe I should be using the DelayQueue class ?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Is it Oracle or OpenJDK? I don't see `aquireQueued` anywhere.

Comment: @JohnVint Oracle, I assume its private method called either when I try to get the DelayLock

Comment: You'll have to queue those queries in a better way than doing a sleep.

Comment: Yes, thats what Im now thinking. But please explain why is Sleep approach worse ?

Comment: Cant work out how do it, this class called by different classes in different threads i.e searchserver.doquery() and then they just wait for the result so I cant put in a queue and come back later ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay using Google Guava Library it turned out to be suprisingly simple

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;
public class SearchServer
{
     private static RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(1.0d);

     static void doDelayQuery()
     {
        rateLimiter.acquire();
     }

     public doQuery()
     ..................
}
```

Although key difference is previously is I took the time of the previous call so didn't wait full second between calls, so to get similar throughput I changed RateLmiter to use 2.0d

Profiling no longer shows cpu hit in this area.

Comment: don't forget that rateLimiter.acquire() here is a blocking call.

Comment: thats the point isnt it to block so doesnt make call too often, or am I missing something ?

Comment: This can be fine if this is contained in a dedicated thread(pool), otherwise, specially on a one-core machine, a blocking call is the same as your previous sleep.

Comment: Please explain futher, when it blocks it doesnt hog the cpu does it ?